# How to get more then 100,000 results in respond using Google BigQuery python API?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-bigquery

Now, I use this script to request Big Query using python API:

```
import argparse
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
bigquery_service = build('bigquery', 'v2', credentials=credentials)

def request(query):
    query_request = bigquery_service.jobs()
    query_data = {'query':query, 'timeoutMs':100000}
    query_response = query_request.query(projectId=project, body=query_data).execute()
    return query_response

query = """
select domain
from 
[logs.compressed_v40_20170313]
limit 150000"""

respond = request(query)
```

I have got results:

```
print respond['totalRows']  # total number of lines in respond 
u'150000'

print len(respond['raws])  # actual number of lines
100000
```

Question: how to receive remaining 50,000 lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get more results after the first page of results, you need to call [getQueryResults](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/python/latest/bigquery_v2.jobs.html#getQueryResults).

In your case, you'll need to get the Job ID and Page Token from the [query](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/python/latest/bigquery_v2.jobs.html#query) response.

```
query_response = query_request.query(projectId=project, body=query_data).execute()
page_token = query_response['pageToken']
job_id = query_response['jobReference']['jobId']
next_page = bigquery_service.jobs().getQueryResults(
    projectId=project, jobId=job_id, pageToken=page_token)
```

Continue this in a loop until you have all query results.

Note: the call to query can time out, but the query will still be running in the background. We recommend you create an explicit Job ID and insert a job manually rather than using the `query` method.

See the ["async" query sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/a2d8238250e6c18e25b5aa3123a7b6ec367613f7/bigquery/api/async_query.py). Note: that it is not quite the proper name, since this sample does wait for the query to finish.